# Access violation exception in Visual Basic 2010 using CUDA as backend DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, video-processing

I have a Visual Basic 2010 front end, which makes calls to a Visual C++ DLL. The Visual C++ DLL consists of calls to CUDA kernel. This is a Video Compression application.

The Visual C++ app, produces `frames` for each video. Frames are stored in files.
Whenever I only run my CUDA app directly without VB front end, it produces fine results.
But when Visual Basic makes calls to CUDA app `main()`. The files get created but after some 1700 files, the VB program throws exception with error

```
AccessViolationException: You tried reading/writing to protected memory.
```

Can anyone please explain, why this is happening?

Comment: From the little information provided, the invalid memory access seems to have nothing to do with CUDA, but  pertains to host system memory access in the VB portion of the code. I would suggest using the appropriate debugging tools available in VB for pin-pointing where the out-of-bounds access occurs. There are myriad possible root causes. One possibility is a failed dynamic memory allocation in VB that goes undetected and gives rise to null pointer de-referencing later on.

Comment: Thank u :). What can be done for the last possibility?

Comment: All the memory allocation is done in cuda program and also made free time to time. No memory allocation is done in VB program, just call to main() is given.

Comment: Please, show Visual Basic Code, and error screenshot/description